# F# : How to provide fst for tuples, triples and quadruples without sacrifying runtime performance

Tags: f#, tuples, inline

For basic Tuples with 2 elements we have fst and snd:

```
let t2 = (2, 3)
fst t2 // = 2
snd t2 // = 3
```

Easy. Now with 3 elements

```
let t3 = (2, 3, 4)
```

how do we access the 3rd element? msdn has an answer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx):

```
let third (_, _, c) = c
```

Still easy. But actually deceptive, because we cannot use fst and snd on such triples:

```
fst t3

error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a int * int but given a int * int * int    
The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 3
```

Hence the challenging question: **How can we provide function *fst* for tuples, triples and quadruples without sacrifying runtime performance?**

Approaches that do not work:

A) simply adding fst(*,*,_)

```
let fst (a,_,_) = a // hides fst (a,b), so tuples dont work anymore
```

B) Any Reflection tricks, since performance is affected or tricky function composition that leads to additional calls at the jitted code level.

C) extension methods (did not lead me anywhere, maybe someone else has better ideas)

```
type Tuple<'T1, 'T2, 'T3> with
    member o.fst(a,b,c) = a
    static member fst(a,b,c) = a
```

besides having other signature (t3.fst()) I could not even get extensions to work with Tuples, although they are classes (not structs).

D)

```
let fst = function 
          | (a,b) -> a
          | (a,b,c) -> a // FS0001: Type mismatch
```

The question is meant as it is formulated, not for workarounds. Actually I believe the answer is that it is not possible to provide common functions that operate on Tuples.

Comment: I think the easiest would be to create functions `fst3`, `snd3`, `third3` for triples and similar for quadruples.
If you need common functions for all kinds of tuples (quint+ etc.) maybe it is worth to consider use other data structure or create custom type.

Comment: http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/11/07/functions-for-n-tuples/ https://code.google.com/p/lib-for-n-tuples/

Comment: (if you really know what you're doing)

Comment: Note many of your parens are unnecessary above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [this technique](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/10/05/inlinefun/) of method overload combined with an inline function has no penalty at all at runtime, since the overload resolution occurs at compile time and the *overloaded* function is inlined at the call site.

There are more complex ways to organise these kind of generic tuple functions in libraries, @MauricioScheffer already posted some links showing more experiments making use of basically the same technique.

Here's a very short standalone code fragment to *overload* the function `fst` to make it work with other tuple sizes:

```
type Fst = Fst with
    static member ($) (Fst, (x1,_)) = x1
    static member ($) (Fst, (x1,_,_)) = x1
    static member ($) (Fst, (x1,_,_,_)) = x1
    // more overloads

let inline fst x = Fst $ x
```

Comment: cool, that is exactly what I was looking for. performance is apparently a bit behind Operators.fst (20% to 50% overhead) but its in the same dimension and im fine with that. will try to attach Operators.fst to the first case, but not a big deal anyway. thx!

Comment: The key is *overloading* as (different) tuples do not unify.

Answer (score 5):

As others already mentioned, there are (more or less elaborate and ugly) ways to do this, but I think the important thing that should be said here is that, if you're using F# well, you *don't need this*.

If you need a data structure that can have two, three or four elements, then you should probably use a list instead of using tuples (in other languages, tuples are sometimes used for this, but not in F#).

If you're working with tuples in F#, then you'll be typically working with a small number of elements (two or three) and then it is more readable to decompose them using pattern matching. Compare the following:

```
// Pattern matching makes you name things, so this is quite clear
// (we don't need the third element, so we're ignoring it)
let width, height, _ = tuple
width * height

// If you had fst3 and snd3, then you could write it using just
// a single line, but the code becomes hard to follow
(fst3 tuple) * (snd3 tuple)
```

So, I think you simply shouldn't be doing this. Now, if you were using more complex data structures (with larger number of elements), then it's better to use something like a record. If your first element is always a "name" and you want to have a function for accessing the name, you can use interfaces (or discriminated unions and pattern matching).

```
type INamed = 
  abstract Name : string

type Person = 
  { SomeName : string }
  interface INamed with
    member this.Name = this.SomeName

type FancyPerson = 
  { SomeName : string; Title : string }
  interface INamed with
    member this.Name = this.SomeName
```

The right approach depends on what you're doing. But in any case, there is most likely a better way of expressing what you need.

Comment: Agreed, this should never come up in practice (and it doesn't in my experience). `fst` and `snd` are convenient because you can pass them in as arguments or compose in `>>` pipelines. Everything else is almost exclusively better served through decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool question.
I think the issue is that F# documentation alludes that it compiles to one of the [Tuple<...>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) objects. So you have to ask yourself, what it the relationship between the types `Tuple<T1, T2>` and `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`? Answer: nothing but the name. There is no relationship at all.

So you can use the library above or you could try to roll your own that includes a relationship.
There's probably a better way to do this, but this is straight forward:

```
type XTuple1<'a>(a: 'a) =
    member public this.fst = a
    abstract member strContents: unit->string
    default this.strContents() = this.fst.ToString()
    override this.ToString() = "(" + this.strContents() + ")"
type XTuple2<'a, 'b>(a:'a, b:'b) =
    inherit XTuple1<'a>(a)
    member public this.snd = b
    override this.strContents() = base.strContents() + ", " + b.ToString()
type XTuple3<'a, 'b, 'c>(a:'a, b:'b, c:'c) =
    inherit XTuple2<'a, 'b>(a, b)
    member public this.thrd = c
    override this.strContents() = base.strContents() + ", " + c.ToString()

let inline xfst<'a> (xt:XTuple1<'a>) = xt.fst
let inline xsnd<'a,'b> (xt:XTuple2<'a,'b>) = xt.snd
let inline xthrd<'a,'b,'c> (xt:XTuple3<'a,'b,'c>) = xt.thrd

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let t3 = XTuple3(1, 'a', "word")
    let a = xfst t3 // strongly typed: a is an int
    let b = xsnd t3
    let c = xthrd t3
    printfn "%s" (t3.ToString()) // -> "(1, a, word)"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```